# Comparing the growth of two polynomials?

Tags: polynomials

For two polynomials, $P(x)$, $Q(x)$, $x \in \mathbb{N}$, both having all positive integer coefficients, and the degree of $P$ is greater than the degree of $Q$, is it true that

$\frac{P(x)}{P(x-1)} > \frac{Q(x)}{Q(x-1)}$,

and how can I prove it?

Comment: For all $x\in \mathbf R$?

Comment: You mean for all $x$?  No.  Let $P(x)=x^2$ and $Q(x)=x$ and let $x=-1$.

Comment: $x \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: But it is true for all sufficiently large $x$. Or if you prefer it is true for all but finitely many positive integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't true. Take P(x) = x^3 + 1000 and $Q(x) = x^2$. Then $P(2)/P(1) = 1008/1001$ and $Q(2)/Q(1) = 2$.

Comment: Thanks - so obvious now you've pointed it out! This particular counterexample depends on the size of the $x^0$ coefficient, right? Is it so easy if there is no $x^0$ coefficient, or a really small one like $1$ or $2$?

Comment: It can happen for polynomials with no constant term as well: just multiply P(x) and Q(x) by x, for instance.

Comment: However, you can show that your inequality holds for sufficiently large $x$, and this in fact only relies on the highest order terms of the two polynomials having the same sign.

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)